# Правила библиографии при коллективном авторстве и авторстве под псевдонимом

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Вопрос не совсем по русскому языку, но, надеюсь, вполне приемлем.
Пришла в голову блажь сделать небольшую сортировку своих электронных книг.
Для себя-то я могу сделать так, как мне будет удобно, но вот если вдруг идея понравится или потребуется кому-то передать...

Хотелось бы понять, как библиографы выходят из положения при авторстве под псевдонимом (считать ли отдельными авторами и т. д.).

Еще хуже с коллективным авторством. Ну понятно, что ***С. Витицкий и С. Ярославцев*** - это совсем даже не ***А. и Б. Стругацкие***. 
Но добило, что в некоторых изданиях "Сказки о Тройке-2" первым автором указан Борис вопреки обычному порядку. Кто знает историю этого произведения - не удивится, оно существует в двух вариантах, так вот к одному варианту руку больше приложил Аркадий - к другому Борис.
Так вот, имею ли я право считать двух коллективных авторов "***Аркадий и Борис Стругацкие"*** и "***Борис и Аркадий Стругацкие***" одним и тем же авторским коллективом?! Или это формально разные авторы?!

Answer (score 3):

При авторстве под псевдонимом Сейчас принято указывать настоящее имя (если известно), а во второй строке, то которое в тексте:

> Ниязов С. А. Рухнама / Сапармурат Туркменбаши. - Ашхабад.: Туркменская государственная издательская служба., 2002. - 416 с.

Если произведение имеет двух авторов, то вначале пишется только первый, а затем оба:

> Валецкий О. В.  Особенности ведения боевых действий в Афганистане (2001–2015). Краткий очерк / Валецкий О. В., Неелов В. М.// М.: Изд. Воробьев А. В., 2015. — 88 с.

В этом случае исчезает проблема считать ли А. и Б. (Б. и А.) Стругацких одним целым или нет, так как в одном случае Аркадий Стругацкий в соавторстве, а во втором Борис. Учитывая, что в приведённом вами примере не просто прихоть издателя, а разные варианты произведения, подобный подход видится наиболее целесообразным.

Comment: Спасибо, кончено, но Вы только запутали. Я так и не понял со Стругацкими, каков ответ? Разные авторы? Ну это ладно, я тут и не ждал понятного и скорого ответа. *А вот чем мне поможет знание того, что Ниязов и Туркменбаши - это один и тот же персонаж?!* Как выборку делать, в каком порядке сортировать?  *На Н или на Т? * Я уж не говорю, насколь это усложняет сам запрос - надо на каждого автора смотреть нет ли к него псевдонима. Т.е. все это делается , конечно, но только если это соответствует реальным потребностям, а не ради "верую, потому, что абсурдно".

Comment: @behemothus по Стругацким - да, разные авторы. В выборке на "Н" (настоящее или более общеупотребительное имя) все псевдонимы автора, а в самом тексте библиографической ссылки указывается под каким именем опубликовано конкретное произведение.